# CSS selector and jQuery eq() matching wrong elements

Tags: jquery, css, preventdefault

I'm having an early morning issue with jQuery. The following code works on `eq(1)` or `eq(0)` but if I try putting it on `eq(2)` or `eq(3)` it just stops, as in it won't add the class to these elements at all, only `eq(0)` and `eq(1)`.

Also, it seems to be preventing the default action on the children too, which shouldn't be happening. It should also be made clear that I am adding the class to certain `<li>`'s for a reason, please bear this in mind. This is why I need to add the class to eq 3 etc. Can anyone shed any light on the issue?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#nav li:eq(2)').addClass('removeLink');
    $('.removeLink').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/6HAvV/

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by "just stops"? With your code above the default action on `The Palms At Corozal` anchor will be removed. Maybe you want children and not descendant `<li>`? For example `ul#nav > li:eq(2)`

Comment: have updated question. It's just not adding the class to any li after eq 0 or eq 1. I need it to be the parent li's that remove the default action, and not the children

Comment: Change to `$('ul#nav li').eq(3).addClass('removeLink');` - http://jsfiddle.net/6HAvV/6/

Comment: It prevents the event on the children links because the event bubbles up, so if you click on a children of an element, is like you have clicked on that element as well.

Comment: Paul, this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will remove the link from the 3<sup>rd</sup> `<li>` selected from *all* of the `<li>`s  (both parent and children) in the list because you are using the CSS [descendent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

The `ul#nav li` will find every single `<li>`. Since you just want to remove the link default action from the first level (CSS children) then you can use the CSS [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

To remove the action from the top level *parent* `<li>`

```
$('ul#nav > li > a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit:** Still using the child selector, this will *only* select the `About Us` link

```
$('ul#nav > li:eq(2) > a')
```

**Edit2:** I was not entirely happy with needing multiple `eq()` selectors so how about using native CSS `nth-child` to select a range instead? This will be quicker in browsers that support `nth-child` natively.

Handy test page for this - http://nthmaster.com/

This should also just colour red (for demo purposes) `Our Projects` and `About Us` with the following code.

**CSS**

```
$('#nav > li:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) > a').css({color: 'red'})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    li class=""><a href="home.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="our-projects.htm">Our Projects</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="the-palms-at-corozal.htm">The Palms At Corozal</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="the-lakes-at-consejo.htm">The Lakes At Consejo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="about-us.htm">About Us</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="who-we-are.htm">Who We Are</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="other-projects.htm">Other Projects</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="partners.htm">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="about-belize.htm">About Belize</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="general-info.htm">General Info</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="investing-in-belize.htm">Investing In Belize</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="useful-links.htm">Useful Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="news.htm">News Articles</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="contact-us.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but it should only be certain classes, hence why i need to add the class to specific li's that shouldn't be firing the default action. I dont want to remove it from all of them

Comment: the .nav_parent suggestion works best, however it is preventing default action on all children of nav_parent

Comment: this is looking good. I also need to select li:eq(3), can i do anything like li:eq(2,3) or something? Just to make it a little more stream lined

Comment: $('ul#nav > li:eq(2) > a, ul#nav > li:eq(3) > a') is how i've done it, works well :)

Comment: Yes this is how I would select multiple `eq()`.

Comment: Small update to use native CSS `nth-child` selector which should be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You may need to prevent click of only those `li`s that has `ul` inside it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#nav > li').has('ul').addClass('removeLink');
    $('.removeLink').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzVSv/3/)

Comment: i dont want to add the class to every li, only certain ones, hence the need for eq